# node muter upload work perfectly on local but got stuck on ubuntu server

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, multer

File upload middleware

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, `${__dirname}/../public/uploads/`);
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, [...Array(64)].map(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * 16).toString(16)).join('') + path.extname(file.originalname));
  }
});

exports.upload = multer({
  storage,
  limits: {
    fileSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024
  },
  fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
    if (file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png') {
      cb(null, true);
    } else {
      cb(null, false);
    }
  }
});
```

Error log middleware

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.log(err);
  res.sendStatus(500);
});
```

Route for upload file

```
router.post('/upload-single', upload.single('image'), (req, res) => {
  // This console log does't print when try to upload file
  console.log('Test request');
  res.status(200).json({
    success: true
  });
});
```

HTML form for upload file

```
<form action="/upload-single" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <input type="file" name="image" accept="image/png,image/jpeg">
    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
```

This code work perfectly at my local computer, but when I try to upload file at production ubuntu server using this code it shows "403 Forbidden" at browser. In backend it doesn't execute route function also.

I try to upload file using node multer package at my ubuntu server but it gives 403 Forbidden error.